# Keep walking after releasing W key in WoW

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I started playing World of Warcraft and I don't know what I did that I kept walking in one direction after releasing the W key. I've tried to repeat this behavior, like clicking in the horizon, but I was unsuccessful.

What is the shortcut or way to keep walking in one direction without keeping pressed the keyboard constantly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<kbd>Num Lock</kbd> should toggle continuous walking ("auto-run").

Comment: It should also be noted that you can change an option that allows you to "click to move". This allows you to right click on the horizon to a destination spot and you will move there and stop at that location.

Comment: would also like to note that a few years back this was also an indication that you may have malicious software installed designed to steal login information. Just be wary if this starts happening randomly.

Comment: @Keibosh Just so I can be clear on what you mean - you're suggesting there was/is malware that randomly triggers autorun?

Comment: I also found the "back" button on a mouse will trigger auto run.

Comment: This was back in vanillia circa 2007 2008. There was a piece of malware that caused your character to get stuck on auto run occasionally. If your worried the best thing you can do to protect your account is use a mobile authenticator.

Answer (score 2):

You can press both of your mouse keys, hold them, then steer by moving the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. As soon as I longer press the w button the char will continue to walk even after I released the button. The problem was my rubber dom (the key itself).
Because we are always pressing w down so hard and so much this key is under large pressure and the rubber is unable to refold itself fast enough. You can test this by using the left and right mouse key to move.